# Batch processing on multiple cores

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I want to do batch processing of files on multiple cores. I have following scenario:

1. I have 20 files.
2. I have a function that takes a filename, processes it and produces an integer result. I want to apply the function to all the 20 files, calculate integer output for each of them and finally sum individual outputs and print the total result.
3. Since I have 4 cores, I can only process 4 files at time. Thus I want to run 5 rounds of processing 4 files at a time (4*5 = 20).
4. That is I want to create 4 processes each processing 5 files one after another (1st process processes files 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 2nd process processes files 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, etc.).

How do I achieve this? I am confused by `multiprocessing.Pool()`, `multiprocessing.Process()` and various other options.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really "want to run 5 rounds of processing 4 files at a time", or just "process 20 files, no more than 4 at a time, as quickly as possible"? Because the latter is a lot simpler (as well as being faster).

Comment: @abarnert: You are correct. I want to process 20 files as quickly as possible and I do not care if each processor strictly gets 5 files each. If one of the processor spends more than average time on one of the files, then I expect other processors pick up remaining work and finish them and not necessarily stop doing work because they have processed their quota of 5 files.

Comment: OK, good, that's exactly what I meant by "as well as being faster". Then Jared's 3-line answer is literally all you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to demonstrate `Pool` I'm going to suppose your working function, which consumes a filename and produces a number, is named `work` and that the 20 files are labeled `1.txt`,... `20.txt`. One way to set this up would be as follows,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.map_async(work, ("%d.txt"%n for n in xrange(1,21)))
print sum(result.get())
```

This method will do the work of steps 3 and 4 for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_file(filename):
    return filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    files = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    results = pool.imap(process_file, files)

    for result in results:
        print result
```

`Pool` automatically defaults to the number of processor cores that you have. Also, make sure that your processing function is importable from the file and that your multiprocessing code is inside of the `if __name__ == '__main__':`. If not, you'll make a fork bomb and lock up your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Now, what's the difference between Pool.map(), Pool.map_async() and Pool.imap(). Which one should be used in which scenario?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: Depends what you want. `imap` returns an iterable while `map` waits for all of the processes to finish and then returns a list.

Comment: Since I want to finally sum the individual results for each file, I suppose I should use map.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: You can sum an iterator just as easily. Basically, it will block on evaluating the iterator inside `sum`, instead of blocking on returning the `list`. When you're dealing with only 20 objects, the difference won't make any difference either way.

Comment: @abarnet: Okay, I get it. So if my function returned a complex object instead of simple int, I would be better off starting processing the complex (time consuming) object than wait for all 20 of them to be returned and then start processing them. Right?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: Yes. Or, if your function just returned an `int`, but you were calling it 5 million times instead of 20, and didn't want to build up a huge list. It's basically the same tradeoff as `range` vs. `xrange`, `map` vs. `imap`, etc. all over Python 2.x. (In 3.x, for the most part, you don't get the list versions of most things anymore.)

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: You should also look at the difference between `map` and `map_async`, and between `imap` and `imap_unordered`.

Comment: @abarnet: Thanks. Now as you say `Pool.imap()` returns an iterable. Suppose I am processing 5 million files as you said. As I progress through iterable, does it free up memory (And if it does that also means that I can only go forward with an iterator)? If it also builds up a list-kind of object then the memory advantage you mentioned isn't simply there.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: Yes, an iterator can only go forward. (You can use `itertools.tee` to mark a point to go back to, or build an explicit cache of values, etc. if you need more.) And it will store no more in memory than needed. For many iterators, that just means one object at a time; `multiprocessing.imap` will actually be storing all the values that have arrived from child processes and not picked up yet (if they're not stored inside the iterator, they're on a queue, which is no better), so that can be anywhere from 0 to all of them, but it's _usually_ just a few.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: One more thing to look at is the `chunksize` parameter. For many cases, you don't care—just let `multiprocessing` guess at a good chunk size and it'll be more than good enough. But if you have a small number of large and highly variable tasks, you might want to test with different explicit chunk sizes. (Too much chunking means less parallelism; too little means more scheduling overhead.)

Answer (score 2):

Although Jared's answer is great, I personally would use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the [`futures`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, and not even worry about `multiprocessing`:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    result = sum(executor.map(process_file, files))
```

When it gets a little more complicated, the `future` object, or `futures.as_completed`, can be really nifty compared to the `multiprocessing` equivalents. When it gets a lot more complicated, `multiprocessing` is a whole lot more flexible and powerful. But when it's this trivial, really, it's almost hard to tell the difference.